# load csv doesn't work, maybe because of it's big size

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import my csv file to neo4j, here is the cypher query:

```
load csv with headers from "file:/Users/mac/Desktop/Dataset.csv" as row with row
merge (u:User {name:row.user, nationality:row.nation})
merge (l:Location {name:row.location,region:row.region})
merge (u) -[t:to {date:row.DateReview,rating:row.rating}]-> (l)
return u,l,t
```

it takes few seconds running then returns back:

```
Cannot merge the following node because of null property value for 'nationality': (:User {nationality: null})
```

the problem that the same query works perfectly for a csv file of 40 lines, but now my csv file is about 17200 lines, plus it's size is 2,2Mo.
thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Yes indeed I did. I try to check this by searching for blaanks in my csv file(especially in nation column) but any missing value appears.

Comment: When you write (:User {nationality: row.nation}), neo4j assumes that nationality is a mandatory field and cannot be blank.  You should use Merge (:User {name:row.user}) Set u.nationality = case trim(row.nation)  when "" then null else row.nation end

Comment: Is the same error coming if you try the given answer as well?

Comment: no, but rather just one relationship and 2 nodes are created, maybe I'm wrong with the code:

Comment: Can you update the whole new code, according to the answer and also add some sample data from the csv along with headers in the question

Comment: yes I did, it  return that message:Set 105040 properties, started streaming 17532 records after 2 ms and completed after 19 ms, displaying first 1000 rows.but just 2nodes and 2relationship are displayed,while the table contain all records but the interaction of the screen becomes very slow.

Answer (score 1):

It means some rows on the column nation is blank (null).  Neo4j do not allow assigning a null value to a property.  If a property is null, that instance property will be skipped. Also check other fields as well like DateReview and rating.

If some of the rows are blank then you can "SET" the values in the cypher query after doing a merge. Trim is making sure a space will be treated as also blank(null).

```
load csv with headers from "file:/Users/mac/Desktop/Dataset.csv" as row 
with row
merge (u:User {name:row.user}) 
set u.nationality = case trim(row.nation) 
    when "" then null else row.nation end 
return u
```

Do not worry about setting the value of nationality to null. Neo4j will not store that nationality:null value in the database.

Please do the same trick (SET) on location.region and to.date

Comment: still not working. I think the problem is not about blank cells because when I give a limit of 8000 for example it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need both properties  `name` and `nationality` for a `:User` to be unique?  If not, you can just `MERGE` on the `name` field.

As a fallback for any fields used in `MERGE` to be empty, you can do

```
MERGE (:User {myMergeField: COALESCE (row.muColumn, '_noValue')})
```

and after the import `DETACH DELETE` all :User nodes with `myMergeField = '_noValue_'`

The fact that your query runs fine if you do a `LIMIT 8000` indicates that there is a data problem after row 8000